# Recommendations for a small O365 tenant-to-O365 tenant migration?

Tags: azure, migration, microsoft-office-365

My (small) team manages the technology for a small college (~600 students), including the college's existing Office 365 tenant. We recently acquired another small college (~125 students) which came with its own O365 tenant.

We'd like to migrate the mailboxes of the acquired tenant into our larger tenant. Budget is shoestring as the acquisition was not known during the annual budgeting process.

We have basic O365 expertise - but none of us have sophisticated O365/azure skills. We've reviewed Microsoft's (high level) O365 migration guide.

Can this be done with freely available / native O365 tools and what would be the specific approach?

Or would such a migration always require additional paid for Microsoft/3<sup>rd</sup> party migration tooling?